# Selenium tests - Everything is printed all the time no matter what

Tags: python, testing, selenium, printing, unit-testing

This might sound like a very silly question but here it is:

I'm writing selenium tests in python, and basically my base test class looks like that:

```
chromedriver = "../selenium-tests/chromedriver"
os.environ["webdriver.chrome.driver"] = chromedriver

class TestsFoo(unittest.TestCase):
    base_url = None
    language = None

    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
        self.verificationErrors = []
        self.accept_next_alert = True
        self.driver.set_window_size(1100, 800)
```

Then all of my other test classes extend from that class. Example:

```
class TestsFooChild(TestsFoo):
    def test_something(self):
        driver = self.driver
        driver.get("{}{}/myurl.html".format(
            self.base_url,
            self.language)
        )
        # do stuff

        print driver.current_url
        self.assertTrue(somethingTrue)

    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.close()
        self.driver.quit()
```

`language` and `url` are defined thanks to this:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    TestsFoo.base_url = os.environ.get('URL')
    TestsFoo.language = os.environ.get('LANGUAGE')
    unittest.main()
```

So that's a lot of informations for a very very tiny question:
When doing unittest, if you let a `print` somewhere, it'll only be printed if the test fails.

Then why in my case, are every `print`s printed no matter what the result of the test is? I only want to print my `current_url` when the test fails.

Also, I'm just looking at why it does that. I'm actively working on finding a way to only print it when my test fails. So that part is taken care of. But I'm curious..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I almost never use `unittest` all by itself but, as far as I can tell, that `print` results in output to the console is the default behavior with `unittest`. Here's an example file:

```
import unittest

class Test(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_one(self):
        print "Foo"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

If you save it as `test.py` and run it with `python test.py`, you'll get `Foo` printed on the console.

However, if you run it with nose like this `nosetests test.py` (or even just `nosetests` in the directory where the file is), you won't see `Foo` on the console. You'd have to run it with `-s` or `--nocapture` to see `Foo`.

Comment: Hah! That's what I wasn't seeing!! Thanks a lot!